# Tag [rpm] has different meanings on different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, tags, site-crossover

I work a lot with [rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpm) (*Redhat Package Manager*) and like to follow the questions with the [rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpm) tag. However I get some questions from "Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair" Stack Exchange site with the `rpm` tag meaning *rotations per minute*.

Should something be done about this?

1. Is it meaningful that tags are shared among all Stack Exchange sites?
2. If yes, how to differentiate the meanings?

Comment: Suppose we have a `table` tag. One on the dba.se, another on the diy.se - why do you think this is a problem? Of course they mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: it is a problem since I receive mails for the `rpm` feed; and don't want the motor and vehicle rpm questions...

Comment: Then you should subscribe to `rpm` on the specific sites where it holds the meaning you are interested in. You _can_ select the sites for the tag subscription.

Comment: One could now argue that the question here should be - "how do I subscribe to tags that have a specific meaning and not include sites that mean something else". No idea why you started backwards here instead of stating the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Go to the tag subscription, click edit, then "Just these sites" radio button - and... choose the sites you want.

Answer (score 5):

> Should something be done about this?

No.

> is it meaningful that tags are shared among all stackexchange sites?

That's your mistake. Tags are not shared between Stack Exchange sites. Each site creates its own tags with their meanings within that specific Stack Exchange site.

> if yes; how to differentiate the meaning?

As I said, no, this is fine. The differentiation? The context of the site they are on.

Answer (score 4):

No, each Stack Exchange site has it's own set of tags. Tags give a hint about the topics which you can ask about on a site, and we don't want any [motor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/motor) questions on Stack Overflow.

> I get some questions from "Motor vehicle maintenance and repair" stackExchange site with the rpm tag meaning rotations per minute.

This is a typical case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) (on *Meta*, nota bene). When you create an advanced tag subscription, select the 'Just these sites' option:

[image]